# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') image.load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Full Error:

> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Code:

```
$("#image").on("load", readImage).each(function ()
            {
                if (this.complete)
                    $(this).load();
            });
```

Most of times it's working but sometimes this error comes what could be the reason?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're calling the [`load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) method which is intended to make an AJAX request and load the content in to the target element. Clearly this is not what you intend, as you don't provide any of the required arguments, and you cannot load content in to an `img`.

To do what you require, just call `readImage()` directly:

```
$("#image").on("load", readImage).each(function() {
  if (this.complete)
    readImage.call(this);
});
```

Also, as a side note, you're selecting the `#image` element by its `id` attribute which implies there should only *ever* be one of them in the DOM. To repeat the same `id` multiple times will cause errors and/or unexpected behaviour. As such, the use of `each()` is redundant.